# Is there a generic way of creating multiple (slightly different) variants of a Bitbake recipe providing the same software?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have multiple variants for the same (custom) software. A few variants support different hardware platforms and other wariants support the same hardware platform but with different feature-set. For example I have:

```
mysoftware.bb (basic version)
mysoftware-qt.bb (basic + qt support)
mysoftware-lic.bb (basic + license support)
mysoftware-qt-lic.bb (basic + license + qt support)
```

My plan was to add `PROVIDES = "mysoftware"` to all of these recipes and `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_mysoftware = "mysoftware-qt"` to my machine conf file.
In my image recipe I wanted to add:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "mysoftware"
```

Many errors came up... like I had to set `RPROVIDES_${PN} = "mysoftware"` in every recipe and had to set `SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST = "/"` in those recipes. (and still not working...)

My question: is there a standard way to achieve this? or is this a bad practice? This seems to be a decent approach for me.

What I wanted to do in the end is:
IMAGE_INSTALL = "... mysoftware" and this will install the appropriate variant and I don't have to do like:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_xhw = "... mysoftware-x"
IMAGE_INSTALL_yhw = "... mysoftware-y"
```

and for those very limited number of times when I have to change from mysoftware to mysoftware-qt I can install it with a package manager (apt in my case):

```
apt install mysoftware-x-qt
```

and as a result the conflicting mysoftware-x would be removed and mysoftware-x-qt would be installed easily.

Comment: As of now I'm getting the following error in image do_rootfs task:

`ERROR: Unable to install packages.
...
Package mysoftware is a virtual package provided by:
  mysoftware-x-qt 4.7.1-r0
  mysoftware-x 4.7.1-r0
...
E: Package 'mysoftware' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score -1):

Inside your recipe  `mysoftware-qt.bb` add:

```
PROVIDES = "virtual/mysoftware"
RPROVIDES_${PN} = "virtual/mysoftware"
```

Inside your machine.conf add :

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/mysoftware = "mysoftware-qt
```

finally add `IMAGE_INSTALL += "mysoftware"` inside your image recipe